# setting UTC Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am creating a rotation schedule using fullcalendar. I need to create events that have start and end dates stored in UTC format.  Regardless of how I am creating my dates, the dates are stored with a timezone.  The dates will also have to be stored in a database. The test data I currently have in the database do not have a timezone and display correctly.
The user selects a start and end date using a datepicker but I add the time in the text box of the datepicker depending on the type of rotation the user has selected.  So the initial start and end dates are from a text field.  The format of these dates are like this:

```
start:   10/30/2015 12:00 AM
 end:     11/19/2015 11:59 PM
```

I need to create a Date object in UTC format.

```
var startDate = convertTextToDate($('#schedule_start_date').val());
var endDate = convertTextToDate($('#schedule_end_date').val());
```

This is the `convertTextToDate` function:

```
function convertTextToDate(dateValue)
{   
    var dateArray = dateValue.split(/\D/);
    var pm = /pm$/i.test(dateValue);
    var hour = (+dateArray[3] || 0) % 12 + (pm ? 12 : 0);
    var date = new Date(Date.UTC(dateArray[2], dateArray[0] - 1, dateArray[1], hour, +dateArray[4] || 0, +dateArray[5] || 0));
    return date;
}
```

When I set a breakpoint at the `return date;` line, the date value **always** is shown with a timezone.  When the events are created and displayed, the times are off by the timezone amount.  The events are created using a `while loop`.  So I have to add 7 days to each rotation.  It creates the number of events expected but the start and end dates are off because, I believe, because it is not in UTC time.
This is the function to create the events:

```
$("#rotation_schedule_btn").click(function () {
//create member list order    
var memberList = [];         
$("#rotationList li").each(function () {
    memberList.push({
        id: $(this).attr('id'),
        name: $(this).text(),
        color: $(this).css('background-color')
    })
});

var startDate = convertTextToDate($('#schedule_start_date').val());
var endDate = convertTextToDate($('#schedule_end_date').val());

//remove events between startDate & endDate
$('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (event) {
    if (event.start.toDate() >= startDate && event.start.toDate() <= endDate
           || event.end.toDate() >= startDate && event.end.toDate() <= endDate) {
        return true;
    }
});

//Create events from rotation schedule selected
var newEvents = [];
var rotation_length = $('#rotation_type_select option:selected').val();
var rotation_start_date = new Date(startDate.toUTCString());
var rotation_end_date = new Date(startDate.toUTCString());

//End date is to midnight
endDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes() + 1);
rotation_end_date.setDate(rotation_end_date.getDate() + parseInt(rotation_length));
var member_index = 0;
while (rotation_end_date <= endDate)
{
    var event = new Object();
    event = {
        title: memberList[member_index].name,
        start: new Date(rotation_start_date.toUTCString()),
        end:  new Date(rotation_end_date.toUTCString()),
        objectID: memberList[member_index].id,
        color: memberList[member_index].color,
        allDay: true,
        textColor: 'white'
    };
    newEvents.push(event);
    eventsAdded.push(event);

    rotation_start_date.setDate(rotation_start_date.getDate() + parseInt(rotation_length));
    rotation_end_date.setDate(rotation_end_date.getDate() + parseInt(rotation_length));

    if ((memberList.length - 1) == member_index) {
        member_index = 0;
    }
    else {
        member_index++;
    }
}           
//Render events on calendar
 $('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newEvents);
});
```

I need to create a Date object with **no** timezone, UTC format.  Regardless of what I do, the date object is off by 4 hours, the time difference between UTC and my timezone.

I know I can display it in UTC format, but that is not what I need. I need to manipulate the date objects to create a events and they have to be in the UTC format.

Comment: tried any library like http://momentjs.com/  ? just saying, never mind

Comment: This is how do it, `JSON.stringify(new Date())` as this would convert it into UTC date time and then you can store this in database.

Comment: tried momentjs and got the same results.

Comment: Before I store it into the database, I need to create the events and store them in the eventsAdded array correctly.  So, first I need to create Date objects without a timezone.  When I create a schedule that goes past November 1st, the daylight savings time kicks in so I really need to do without the time zone.